# Can't figure out why the number of spaces are not counted

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been teaching learning c++ and I've been trying to make a program that takes a string of characters and removes the white spaces using pointers. Everything is working but I want it to ouput the number of spaces removed. The code looks all correct on my tired eyes. I have number of spaces defined as spaces. Pretty self explanatory what i'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int stripWhite(char *str);


int main()
{
char str[100];
cin.getline(str, 99);    // save room for the null character.


stripWhite(str);
cout << str << endl;

cout << "I removed " << stripWhite(str) << " from this sentence.";



return 0;
}


int stripWhite(char *str)
{
char *p;    
int spaces = 0;

for (p = str; *str != '\0'; ++str) 
{
    if (*str != 0x20)
    {
         *p++ = *str;

    }
    else
    {
        spaces++;

    }

}
*p = '\0';  

return spaces;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're calling `stripWhite` on your string *twice* (the first time throwing away the number removed) so obviously there'll be nothing to remove the second time.

You need to call it once and save the return value, something like:

```
int count = stripWhite(str);
cout << str << endl;

cout << "I removed " << count << " from this sentence.";
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already removed the spaces when you called the stripWhite(str) first time so when you are calling it again next time there is nothing to remove so each time you will end up with 0 spaces.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

remove your first call of `stripWhite(str);` the below line is enough to count spaces.

```
cout << "I removed " << stripWhite(str) << " from this sentence.";
```